# Devenv.com does not see one csproj in the sln file (command line build via Azure DevOps)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, devenv, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I've got a solution file (VS 2017 enterprise) which contains 12 projects - mostly csproj, and a couple of vdproj.  I've got the Visual Studio Installer Projects extension installed.

When I build from within Visual Studio, everything builds fine.

When I build from the command line using "devenv solution.sln /Rebuild Release" everything builds fine.

When I build from Azure DevOps using the Command Line task, one of the csproj projects is not build.  It doesn't fail.  It isn't skipped.  It's just ignored completely, like devenv doesn't see it.  But the exact same command, when executed manually from a command prompt, works fine.

I can't use msbuild because of the vdproj projects.

I've tried everything I can think of, and am stumped.  Any tips?

**Edit**: ProjectTypeGuids contains fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc (C#) and 349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21 (Web Application / Web Service). Sln file just lists fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc.

**EDIT 2**: If I change the Build Agent to run as my user account, instead of the local Network Service account, it runs just fine.  So there's something about the Visual Studio installation, I'm guessing, which the Network Service account doesn't have access to?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you've tried already?  My guess is you have a build artifact already in place locally that is not actually committed to source control.  You should try cloning the repository fresh locally and see if you can continue to build.

Comment: Do you use a Hosted agent or a Private agent?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk private agent.

Comment: @raterus I do clean builds every time.  I've cloned the repository fresh locally, as well as tried building in build agent's work directory (to make sure I'm building off exactly waht the build agent has). I've built from VS.  I've built from command line. I've used /Build and /Rebuild. I've copied/pasted the exact command from the build log.  I've stopped the build immediately before the offending step and run that step manually from the command prompt in the build agent's work folder.  Always when I run it manually, it works, but when Build Agent runs it, it ignores one csproj.

Comment: `When I build from Azure DevOps` is this building from a repo? If so compare your .sln with the repo .sln and make sure the csproj and associated files are added to the repo appropriately

Comment: Yes - and they are all there.  When I go into the build agent's _work folder and run the same command the build agent failed on, it works.  And new piece of info I just tried, added as edit 2 in main post